# Below API level 24 => Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I am getting this exception when I am running my code below API level 24.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.scanwithanimations,
>   PID: 13393 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.scanwithanimations/com.example.scanwithanimations.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error
>   inflating class

android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

My **main.xml** is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_wifi"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/fabwifi"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/fab1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Its **JNE** (java.lang.NullPointerException) my friend

Comment: @NileshRathod But it is working fine API 26...

Comment: @Pritam share your layout.xml file

Comment: @NileshRathod Plz check it

Comment: @Pritam check my below ans and let me know it work or not

Comment: @NileshRathod I checked that also it is not working..!!

Comment: can you share your gradle app file

Comment: @NileshRathod I uploaded...

Comment: @Pritam did change my ans in your all `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: @NileshRathod Thnx...
I forgot to change in one place.
It is working fine now.
Thank you very much for helping...

Comment: @NileshRathod 
I accepted but as I am created this account today and I also having less reputation...
It is showing "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @NileshRathod    Done....
Thnx...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use  this**

- `app:elevation="6dp"`
- `app:backgroundTint="@color/fab1"`

**insted of this**

- `android:elevation="6dp"`
- `android:backgroundTint="@color/fab2"`

**sample code**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="164dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_wifi"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/fabwifi"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```